# Hide local filenames in Browserify output?

Tags: browserify

When you bundle your code with Browserify, each module you use is inlined in the resulting output and labeled with its local file path. So you can see file path strings in your bundled code.

But in theory, these strings could all be rewritten to "1", "2", etc, which might be a security advantage in some situations (and would save a few bytes).

Is there any option for this, or some transform that will do it? (It would have to rewrite the labels for each inlined module, and all the corresponding `require` calls.)

Comment: What are you using to call browserify? I was running into this myself, but only if I used gulp-browserify and ONLY if I set insertGlobals to true. It also appears https://github.com/substack/node-browserify node-browserify has an --insert-globals parameter that might cause this.

Comment: I have this same issue. It only happens when using a global transform though and I can actually fix it by setting `insertGlobals: true` at the cost of a bigger file size.

Comment: I think [bundle-collapser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-collapser) does exactly what you needed a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that 6 months after your question, Browserify's author James Halliday put [Bundle Collapser](https://github.com/substack/bundle-collapser) out there. It does pretty much exactly what we were both after.

Answer (score -1):

The insert globals option may be enabled with any of the following aliases

`--insert-globals` 
`--ig`
`--fast`

If you remove all of those, your build may be slightly slower but it will remove the names.

Comment: this doesn't seem to affect the module identifiers in output. I always get full strings for file paths in the output with browserify 3.38.1